# How can I get only the currentVersion from PowerCLI?

Tags: powershell, powercli

I'm trying to obtain only the latest version number

For example: ESXi 6.0 Update 2

This is what I have done:

```
$esxitest = Get-VMHost esxitest.test.local | Get-VMHostLatestVersion

Write-Host "Version:" $esxitest
```

Answer (score 0):

Expand the `Version` property of the returned object:

```
$esxitest = Get-VMHost esxitest.test.local |
            Get-VMHostLatestVersion |
            Select-Object -Expand Version
```